# UIButton doesn't dispatch touch event after uitextview becomes first responder

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextview, touch-event, first-responder

I have an `UITextView` that should become the first responder (display the keyboard) when the controller loads. The only thing is, that I have 'inflated' two `UIView` which each contain an `UIButton`. The touch events on these buttons do work when the `UITextView` is not yet the first responder, but after the `UITextView` becomes the first responder, the `UIButtons` are not responding to any tap-events..

How do I make sure the buttons still work when the textview becomes the first responder?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you. It did work for me..

In `UIButton`'s `IBAction` method check whether your text field is the first responder. 
If it is the first responder resign it.
That will dissmiss the keyboard and perform the buttons action.

```
-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender
 {
  if ([txt isFirstResponder]) 
   {
    [txt resignFirstResponder];
   }
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"hi" message:@"Hello" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
 [alert show];
}
```

[image: Button action plus resigning first responder]

Comment: This didn't work, since the IBAction that was added to the button wasn't fired at all. It never came into that method..

Comment: @SanderBruggeman : Can you add your IBAction code? Because it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the button initialization to lazy might fix the problem, as was suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49604460/4884617).